# Can't push many or large files to gitlab self hosted rep

Tags: git, gitlab

suddenly i made up self hosted gitlab on my ubuntu 20v. But, sometimes i can't push large commits to rep and get this error.

> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

This error fixes by pushing small numbers of files

MB exact some limiter for pushing in gitlab config but i can't find it in gitlab admin panel

Comment: How big are the files? Are you using HTTP or SSH to push?

Comment: using http, some files can be around 100-200mb